# Is it possible to specify that jQuery only searches within a particular div on the page?

Tags: jquery

In the selector syntax of jQuery `$('.string')`, is it possible to specify that the search is performed only within a particular div or element on the page?

I ask because I am using a web application framework which has a bug, namely producing container elements with the same id so when I search by id to find the container programmatically, it returns the first container out of the many containers with the same id.

But the container I want always has a unique class attibute. So if I could select that container and tell jQuery to perform it's queries within that container I would have a solution. Is this possible?

Apologies if a basic question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the space operator in the selector, i.e. specify that you want to seach for children of the elements with the class:

```
$('.TheUniqueClass .SomeOtherSelector')...
```

You can also use an element as scope for the search:

```
var container = $('.TheUniqueClass');
$('.SomeOtherSelector', container)...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".searchInHere").find(".searchForThis")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".foo") // select all elements with the class foo
```